# How to add video file in video.js 4.2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video.js

I downloaded the video-js-4.2.1.zip from http://www.videojs.com/ and in demo.html I changed the source file for the video but it won't load. I've even inputed the full http:// adress and still doesn't work. It only works with the demo video from http://www.videojs.com/ . How to make it to work?

Respectfully,
Vasile Lucian BUJOR

PS. Here is the code ( I add a png for the poster and removed the captions from the original code and renamed demo.html to index.html ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video</title>

  <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>

  <!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>


</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360"
      poster="principal.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="/wildelife.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="/wildelife.webm" type='video/webm' />
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to check the documentation on the github repository ( https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/setup.md ).

Also try not making a / in front of the video-path. Try:

```
<source src="wildelife.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

if the path to the file is in the same folder like your .html-file.

I don’t know what else to say, it’s perfectly working over here. You could check on your folder structure anyways.

hope that helps